# H2O Data prep export to POJO

Tags: r, h2o

I'm new to H2O project but have a lot of interest to use it for my web application. I've made a few tutorials building a model with `h2o` library in R and then exporting it as `POJO` model.

My problem is that the data I need to predict is in different format I used for train dataset. I am wondering is it possible to use my R code with data transformation and export it as `POJO` (or similar) so I could prepare a new data for prediction in real time.

I've found some examples in "Productionizing H2O" section on H2O docs page ([link](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/1/docs-website/h2o-docs/productionizing.html)), like `Consumer loan application` and `Storm bolt`. But in first case they use the same set of features and in the second one data prep is done with .java code (not sure on that, I have a poor programming skills outside of R). So I am not able to figure out how to use my transformation code in R on a new dataset.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You have four options:
(**EDIT**: added third option)
(**EDIT 2**: added fourth option for MOJOs -- recommended)

1. You can keep the prediction pipeline in R and make use of the `h2o.predict_json()` function, which allows you to pass your test data as JSON in R to a MOJO/POJO on disk to generate predictions.  This would allow you to use your R code for data munging, and then you'd take the munged data, convert it into a JSON string, and use `h2o.predict_json()` to generate the predictions.  The function expects a single row at a time, so if you have a whole data frame, you'd have to write a loop.  The predictions would be in R memory at that point, so you could choose to write them to a file/database or do something else with them in pure R.
2. Translate the R data munging code into Java and keep your application Java only, using the POJO/MOJO directly from your Java application.
3. Keep using your R code for munging, write the munged data to disk using a fast I/O tool like `data.table::fwrite()`, then use that new file as the input to the POJO/MOJO and score in Java.  This way you can score a whole file at once rather than #1 where you have to score a row at a time.
4. We now have two convenience functions, [`h2o.mojo_predict_df()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.mojo_predict_df.html) and [`h2o.mojo_predict_csv()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.mojo_predict_df.html), which allows you to score a dataset from R using an efficient MOJO model.  What you can do here is to write some data transformation code in R, and then pass the transformed data.frame to `h2o.mojo_predict_df()` (assuming you have exported the model to MOJO format using the [`h2o.download_mojo()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.download_mojo.html) function).  This allows you to keep your scoring pipeline entirely in R, but you will get the speed of using an optimized MOJO model.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, Erin! The first option is exactly what I was doing without h2o, using models from skparklyr package. But I don't see so efficient the orchestration of the whole process from R in real time. That was my principal motivation to try h2o. Actually I saw the scheme on h2o webpage ([link](https://www.h2o.ai/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/h2o-architecture-1.png)) pointing out data prep export to POJO in the same way as models. So I am feeling a bit disappointed about that.

Comment: You don't have to use R the whole time, just for the data munging and even though you are calling the prediction code from R, it's scoring in Java (so it's faster).    

Do you know about rsparkling (H2O via sparklyr) would help?  That way you could do munging in Spark (instead of R) but you can still use to orchestrate. http://spark.rstudio.com/guides/h2o/  https://github.com/h2oai/rsparkling

Comment: @AndriyT. I added a third option.

Comment: yes, I am using rsparkling for create an h2o instance over spark and operate with sparkdataframe converted to h2o with rsparkling::as_h2o_frame() function. Thank's for pointing that out.

Comment: Based on your 3 option I gonna try to compare: 1. Load new data set to R, transform and write to disk, score it in Java using model stored as POJO. 2. Load new dataset and h2o model to R, transform and predict in the same session, write results to disk.

Comment: @ErinLeDell this is super helpful! but can you tell which approach is more efficient when deploying the model in azure through API management? Our training data is huge so we use spark for pre-processing and H2O for modeling, however scoring data is not huge, and doesn't need a distributed setting and therefore we are exporting the mojo and are planning to use that for productionalizong

Comment: @EmmaNej I just added a fourth option which may be of interest to you.

Answer (score -1):

Handling the data munging before an H2O makes a prediction is something you need to handle.

One strategy is to write your munging code in such a way that you can execute the same exact code for both training and production environments.

Comment: I understand, so that's why I am looking for help to find the best way to do that.